# How to run a bash script from PHP

Tags: bash, php

I have below php file to run a bash script...

```
<?php
    
    $old_path = getcwd();
    chdir('/home/scripts/');
    $var = escapeshellarg("PC7");
    $output = shell_exec("./Script2.sh $var");
    chdir($old_path);
    echo $output;
    
 ?>
```

and Here is my Script2.sh file...

```
 #!/bin/bash
    
    var=$1
    
    if [ "$var" == "PC7" ]; then
        echo "Strings are equal"
    else
        echo "Strings are not equal"
    fi
```

Now I need to use this inside a PHP function to execute whenever I click a button... Here is my attempt. But I am not getting `Updated successfully- Strings are equal` as output. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
<input type="button" style="background-color:#00BFFF;padding:3px;border: none;"  class="button" name="pc7" value="Get The Latest"/>


$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.button').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).attr('name');
        var ajaxurl = 'runscripts_intvoice.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
            
            alert("Updated successfully -"+response);

        });
        
       
    });

});
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why are you calling a bash script? If this is intended to just be an example short code version of your logic, it is confusing because in this example, there is no purpose that I can see for the bash part. What are you actually trying to achieve? or is this just a homework assignment? Also, why are you sending json to PHP, what's the point of that? That's probably why it's not working, that should be a string, not json, since you are testing for a string in the PHP/bash. Try as a start to read the documentation on these, otherwise you will never learn.

Comment: Is the script executable? i.e. `ls -l Script2.sh` shows `rwxr-xr-x`? If not you can change that with `chmod 755 Script2.sh`. That would help, to get some response. If you wonder why the string is not equal, you can log the parameter your receive. In PHP you do: `error_log("My string is [" . $my_string . "]");`.